# UI plugin for image upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, user-interface, upload

Can someone please suggest a good lightweight and customizable UI plugin for uploading images? I am currently using an HTML file input for this for now, which is really ugly and is browser dependent for view.

Some of the requirements of my project are that the plugin should -
1) Not take much screen real estate
2) Be able to restrict the type and number of files that can be uploaded

Comment: http://www.uploadify.com should do the trick

Comment: Thanks Mike, unfortunately, uploadify uses flash. I wanted something purely javascript/html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works really well for me [ajax-upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)